# How to remove trailing <br /> tags with JSoup?

Tags: whitespace, jsoup, htmlcleaner

I use a WYSIWIG html component to allow my customers to enter html content and I clean it up on the server side using JSoup. Sometimes (depending on the browser and the user), the content that gets submitted contains empty tags (like `<p>`), or whitespace tags (like `<br />`).  These are annoying since for all intents and purposes the input is blank, but the length of the string is non-zero.

Does anyone know if there is a JSoup setting that allows me chomp off all trailing tags that contain no content?

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup's getText() method may help you.

if  < div class="data">

```
< br >MY Name is < /br > 
< br>Chirag< /br>
< br> < / br>
```

< /div>

than Elements data=doc.getElementsByClass("data") ,data.getText() gives you "My Name is Chirag" .